# Trapping Java applet cancel button

Tags: java, javascript, applet, java-native-interface

I have a Java applet that runs with no UI and sends XML back to the calling Javascript for processing to a database.  I have the applet set up to do a callback once the applet is initialized using an Init override and the callback is a Javascript function that proceeds to do some work with another applet method.

If the user clicks the "No" button on Java security warning however, no applet code is ever run and the calling page waits forever for the callback to occur.  Is there a way to trap the user declining the security warning in Javascript?

Please no questions on why I'm using an applet for this, it's a very complicated infrastructure (out of my control) which involves multiple web vendors and this is the only architecture I've found that meets all the other requirements.

Answer (score 1):

About the best you can do is poll for the applet appearance in JS, and if it doesn't appear after a 'length of time', pop an alert to the user offering to redirect to help (or wait - if they are still looking over the details offered by the security dialog/pop-up).

Use applets, expect trouble.  Use *hidden* applets, expect ***chaos***..

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks.